# IE 11 - Favorites Bar can not be enabled, option greyed out

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, group-policy, internet-explorer-11

The option to enable the favorites bar in Internet Explorer 11 is greyed out and can not be enabled. 
[image: Screenshot]

I can add new favorites though. OS is Windows 7. The clients are domain joined and options for IE are set but I can not see which option should disable the bar or what is interfering.

What I tried so far:

- disabled Antivirus
- start IE with all Add-Ons disabled
- explicitly enabled the favorites bar in GPO: `User Configuration - Policies - Administrative Templates - Windows Components - Internet Explorer - Turn off Favorites bar` -> set to `disabled`
- `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\MINIE` set `LinksBandEnabled` to 1
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LinksBar` set `Enabled` to 1
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LinksBar` set `Enabled` to 1
- make sure `Enhanced Protected Mode` is off
- reset settings (`Resets Internet Explorer's settings to their default condition.`)

Still no success. What can I do to enable the favorites bar again?
[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943525/internet-explorer-11-favourite-bar-greyed-out) without answer.

EDIT:

- Denied read access for GPO with IE settings for a test user. Made sure GPO was not pulled on the client (checked with RSoP). Favorites bar is still greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

Try excluding 1 user from the GPO (deny read access), then refresh the GPO with "gpupdate /force" and see if the problem persist. Also make sure you don't have a computer GPO that may also affect this settings.

Comment: Thanks. Denied read access to a test user, restarted the client but still no luck. I also checked with RSoP, the GPO was not applied.

Comment: Does the problem appear on all workstation? If yes it might be something in your source image that is wrong, try to take a workstation completely off the domain and log in as local administrator on the machine to double check the problem is not coming from the domain and if you still have the same problem then try installing a fresh workstation from scratch, fully update it, test the favorites bar and all still works good join the domain and check again.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. Verify security settings of `%USERPROFILE%\Favorites` to ensure the user has write access to this folder.
2. Verify if IEAK was used to deploy IE previously. Back in the day, a custom build of Internet Explorer could be deployed using the Internet Explorer Administration Kit (IEAK). A lot of options could be tweaked by the IEAK. Possibly one of those settings carried forward to IE11 if you've upgraded from previous versions.

Comment: Thanks! 1. Yes, the users have write access (all domain users are affected). 2. Mhh, we never used IEAK. IE11 came with a Win 7 image and it worked in the past...